# Links that I have in 'navbar' overlaps each other:/

Tags: python, django, url, django-urls

Hello everyone:) Links that I have in 'navbar' overlaps each other when I make a transition into another link. For instance, I have a navbar menu with four different links (home, catalog, distributors and contacts) and 'home' is a base webpage. I.e when I make a transition from the base webpage 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' to catalog I get this http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog (all right) but then I make a transition into section 'distributors' and then I get this 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/distributors (and it's not normal) How to rectify this?
My url patterns seems right :/

```
   urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
   url(r'^catalog/$', views.catalog, name='catalog'),
   url(r'^distributors/$', views.distributors, name='distributors'),
   url(r'^contacts/$', views.contacts, name='Contacts'),
   ]

template:
<div class="header">
  <div id="inner">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="image"><p><a href="/">HOME</a></p></div>
            <div class="filter1"></div>
            <div class="filter2"></div>
            <div class="txt">
              <p>We greet you on the main</p>
              <p>page of our website!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="image"><p><a href="catalog">CATALOG</a></p></div>
            <div class="filter1"></div>
            <div class="filter2"></div>
            <div class="txt">
              <p>Browse through our catalog</p>
              <p>and select the good just for you.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="image"><p><a href="distributors">DISTRIBUTORS</a></p></div>
            <div class="filter1"></div>
            <div class="filter2"></div>
            <div class="txt">
              <p>We are currently expanding our</p>
              <p>distributor network into new markets.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="image"><p><a href="contacts">CONTACTS</a></p></div>
            <div class="filter1"></div>
            <div class="filter2"></div>
            <div class="txt">
              <p>You can always communicate with us</p>
              <p>using section "Contacts". </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

views:
def home(request):
products_images = ProductImage.objects.filter(is_active=True, is_main=True, product__is_active=True)
products_images_with = products_images.filter(product__category__id=1)
products_images_without = products_images.filter(product__category__id=2)
return render(request, 'landing/home.html', locals())

def catalog(request):
products_images = ProductImage.objects.filter(is_active=True, is_main=True, product__is_active=True)
return render(request, 'landing/catalog.html', locals())

def distributors(request):
return render(request, 'landing/distributors.html', locals())

def contacts(request):
return render(request, 'landing/Contacts.html', locals())
```

Can someone help me with this problem? Django version 1.11.2

Comment: Hello. Could you update your question with the code containing the link to access to section 'distributors'? The error is probably in the view or the template, not in the urls declaration.

Comment: additions added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way you use links in your Django templates.

Take a look to: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url

You have to use a `{% url 'url-name-here' %}` sothat Django will build url by itself.

For example, in your case:

```
<div class="image"><p><a href="{% url 'catalog'%}">CATALOG</a></p></div>
```

This way:

- it's a lot easier for you, you just provide the url name and let Django generated the real url.
- you don't repeat yourself; if you want to change the path of the url, you only need to do it one time in urls.py.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and for the details! It's fine now:)

Comment: You're welcome. If you have some time, you can do the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/) which covers this concept and many other ones.

Answer (score 1):

As @David D. answered, you should use the method of url building  as it provides you flexibility.

But, if for some reason you want that absolute URLs should be specified in href, then while using absolute urls the above problem can be solved by prepending a forward slash to each url name when assigning to href.

So your new urls should look like :

```
<a href="/catalog">CATALOG</a>
<a href="/distributors">DISTRIBUTORS</a>
<a href="/contacts">CONTACTS</a>
```

The reason it works is that / represents root of website, so using '/' routes you to the root and using  '/catalog' routes you to the catalog page directly from the root.